# finding expected value

Tags: probability, inequality, expected-value

The White Rabbit has a very poor memory, and so he is constantly forgetting his regularly scheduled appointments with the Queen of Hearts. In an effort to avoid further beheadings of court officials, The King of Hearts has installed an app on Rabbit’s pocket watch to automatically remind Rabbit of any upcoming appointments. For each reminder Rabbit receives, Rabbit has a $50$ percent chance of actually remembering his appointment (decided by an independent fair coin flip).

First, suppose the King of Hearts sends Rabbit $k$ separate reminders for a single appointment

a) What is the exact probability that Rabbit will remember his appointment? Your answer should be a simple function of $k$.

(b) What value of $k$ should the King choose so that the probability that Rabbit will remember this appointment is at least $1 − 1/n^α$? Your answer should be a simple function of $n$ and $α$.

Now suppose the King of Hearts sends Rabbit $k$ separate reminders for each of n different appointments. (That’s $nk$ reminders altogether.)

(c) What is the exact expected number of appointments that Rabbit will remember? Your answer should be a simple function of $n$ and $k$.

(d) What value of $k$ should the King choose so that the probability that Rabbit remembers every appointment is at least $1 − 1/n^α$? Again, your answer should be a simple function of $n$ and $α$.

I have already computed part a,b,c but stuck at (d). Part (a) should be $1-(1/2)^k$, part(b) should be $k \geq \alpha lnn$, part (c) should be $n(1-(1/2)^k)$

But for part (d), What I got so far is $P(\text{rabbit remember all n appointment}) = (1- (1/2)^k)^n$, and I want $(1- (1/2)^k)^n \geq 1 − 1/n^α$, but then I'm stuck at solving the inequalities or is this a right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your work up to this point is mostly correct.  Part (b) should be $$k \ge \alpha \frac{\log n}{\log 2} = \alpha \log_2 n.$$  In other words, the base of the logarithm needs to be $2$; using the natural logarithm $\ln$ which has base $e$, is incorrect.

For part (d), You need to solve the inequality $$(1 - (1/2)^k)^n \ge 1 - 1/n^\alpha,$$ which leads to $$1 - (1/2)^k \ge (1 - 1/n^\alpha)^{1/n}$$ hence $$(1/2)^k \le 1 - (1 - 1/n^\alpha)^{1/n}.$$ Taking logarithms yields
$$k \log (1/2) \le \log \left(1 - (1 - 1/n^\alpha)^{1/n}\right).$$  Finally, divided by $\log (1/2) = -\log 2$:  $$k \ge -\frac{\log \left(1 - (1 - 1/n^\alpha)^{1/n}\right)}{\log 2} = - \log_2 \left(1 - (1 - 1/n^\alpha)^{1/n}\right).$$  Although this number looks negative, it is not, since $n \ge 1$ and $\alpha > 0$ implies $0 \ge 1 - 1/n^\alpha < 1$, hence $0 \ge (1 - 1/n^\alpha)^{1/n} < 1$, hence $0 < 1 - (1 - 1/n^\alpha)^{1/n} \le 1$, and so the logarithm (to any base) of this number will be negative or $0$.